# How to modify Bad credentials message in spring security login?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-form

How to modify `Bad credentials` error message in spring security login?

SecurityFilterChain

```
    public SecurityFilterChain applicationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable();
        http.cors().and().authorizeHttpRequests().permitAll();
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                //  .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
            // authorization server filter chain
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Also, added `messages_en.properties` files in the `src/main/resource`

```
message.badCredentials=Invalid user name and password
```

Still getting the same error message.

Spring boot 3.0.6

Comment: what do you mean modify? what is it you want to actually do?

Comment: Change the default error message.

Comment: @dur, that is not working, and the link you provided is for legacy oauth. not the new oauth (i.e 2.1). compactable with spring boot 3 and above

Comment: @Thirumal OAuth2? Your Spring Security configuration doesn't contain OAuth2. If you use OAuth2, you should show your real Spring Security configuration.

Comment: @Thirumal The answer in the other question is still working with Spring Boot 3/Spring Securits 6, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6.0.3/core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/messages.properties